# Looking for Java class to retrieve SVN version information in SVN 1.7

Tags: java, svn, working-copy

For an Ant extension we have a Java class which retrieves the highest svnrevision number in a local working copy. The class already supports up to SVN 1.6 but we have to change it to support SVN 1.7 using the local wc.db. I have googled some time now on this subject, but cannot find a clear hint how to solve this.

Is there any example code available how to retrieve the revision number from a SVN 1.7 working copy, equivalent to what the svnversion binary does ?

Cheers
Peter

Answer (score 1):

[SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/), the only Java SVN API I know, only supports Subversion 1.6.5. But maybe the feature you are looking for is already working? It's worth to give it a try, imo.

Comment: This not true: http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/tags/1.3.6/CHANGES.txt (Support 1.6.17!)...

Comment: I just wrote what the SVNKit doc says, which is "Latest SVNKit supports Subversion 1.6.5". Take a look here: http://svnkit.com/documentation.html

Answer (score 1):

Parsing subversion metainfo in order to get latest revision number IMHO is not a good idea.

Actually, there is another standard way of getting revision number. You could use `svn:keywords` in order to get current revision number in your files after each commit. There is `$Revision$` property for revision substitution. You just need to put following string into the file and place this file under version control:

```
$Revision$
```

If you need to use revision property in ant, I would recommend putting following content into version.properties file:

```
revision=$Revision$
```

Then include in into the `build.xml` with the statement:

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
```

And then you will be able to use revision number in your build script:

```
<echo message="Deploying revision ${revision}" />
```

Please also note that you will need to explicitly enable `svn:keywords` using subversion properties in order to get `$Revision$` substituted in your file with actual value. If you use `version.properties` for getting revision number value, you will need to run following command:

```
svn propset svn:keywords Revision version.properties
```

Not sure that will work for your case, but that's the approach I use most often in my projects if I want to use revision number during the build process. This approach is definitely better than getting revision number from the working copy metainfo.

Answer (score 0):

Was SVNKit too simple: [SVNKit alpha version supports already SVN 1.7](http://svnkit.com/download.php) working copy format...so just give it a try...